# Joomla - How can I opt one from various modules to display in a position

Tags: joomla, joomla-module

I am willing to create a logic in which If I can fetch only desirable module in a particular position.

As we know that Joomla displays the module on basis of positions given to modules created, hence there could be several modules for a single position.

Now what If I only want a single module from those modules who has the position, say "positon-1".

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at Advanced Module Manager? It has a whole bunch of ways you can filter modules. http://www.nonumber.nl/extensions/advancedmodulemanager

Answer (score 0):

Each module can be told to be shown only on specific pages. Look in the module settings at the "Menu Assignment" part. There you can set it to show on

- all pages
- No pages
- Only on the pages selected
- On all pages except those selected

So you can set a module to show on the homepage in `position-1`, but on all other pages there is a different module shown on the same position.

Answer (score 0):

Don't  position names like `position-1`, although the example templates shipped with Joomla! do so. Use *semantic* names for the module positions. Then, within your template, you define, where these positions live.

> Now what If I only want a single module from those modules who has ... [a certain] position

That will never happen then. You're going to have a position called `search` where the serach field is located, and maybe another one called `navigation`, where you publish your navigational menus. You get a lot more positions, but also much more flexibility. So if you have a module that needs its own position as in your question, let's have it that.